# My computer often restarts randomly, how do I know what's the issue?

Tags: reboot

It has been happening for long.

I have no idea why.

We changed GPU. We changed fans to make sure that CPU is cool. We changed power supply.

We really have no idea why.

It just restart.

I wonder if there is an app that can log things like temperature or anything that can enable us to see why the computer is restarting again and again?

System log shows this

[image]

The windows Event Viewer show this

[image]

Basically it simply says the last error is unexpected

[image]

Not really sure it is relevant but I also have this 30 minutes before restart

[image]

Nothing shows up in system log. I only got an entry in system log after the computer restart with no info why it got restarted

[image]

Note: Making the CPU cooler with $30 fans **REDUCES** restart but not eliminating it.

Comment: Bad or incompatible RAM can do this.

Comment: Memory tests fine. Windows event shows (i'll post the pics)

Comment: Have you looked in the system event logs?

Comment: you mean event viewer?

Comment: No, he means the system event logs which you LOOK AT via the event viewer.

Comment: I posted that pic too

Comment: I would get a Kubuntu Linux flash drive (or similar), run memtest86 from it, run Kubuntu from the flash drive and see if that crashes. That would rule out RAM and OS.

Comment: I did windows memory test. The memory was fine